# How do I use my server as a proxy to download files via PHP?

Tags: php, proxy, download

I need my server to act as a proxy between a 3rd party server (where the file is originally located) and the end user. That is, my server downloads the file from the 3rd party server, and sequentially, the user downloads it from my server. This should result in an incurred bandwidth of twice the file size. How can this process be achieved using PHP?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Very very simply like this:

```
$url = $_GET['file'];
$path_parts = pathinfo($url);

$ext = $path_parts['extension'];
$filename = $path_parts['filename'];

header("Content-type: application/$ext");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

echo file_get_contents($url);
```

If the file is larger than a few  megabytes, use fopen fread and frwrite download the file in chunks and send to the client in chunks.

Comment: You can use `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");` if your filename contains spaces

Answer (score 17):

```
        $fp = fopen($url, 'rb');
        foreach (get_headers($url) as $header)
        {
            header($header);
        }

        fpassthru($fp);
        exit;
```

This will simply download a remote file to the browser with correct headers.

Comment: This is actually a pretty good solution with the least downside.

Comment: does exacly what it says on tin, and what op asked for, should be accpeted anwser.

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents()` will not load the page until the entire file is downloaded to memory

`readfile()` will show the page right away yet continue downloading the file in memory, streaming it to the client

Example usage using an EXE:

```php
$url = "https://path/to/file.exe";
$filename = "SaveAsFile.exe
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

readfile($url);
```