# Use my server as proxy on downloads via PHP

Tags: php, download, proxy

I need my server to act as a proxy between a 3rd party server (where the file is originally located) and the end user.

So, the user will have a download link like myserver.com/file?90812949
and the server will act like a proxy on the download that the data pass from the server before being sent to the user.

Original File Host => My Server => User

Note that i'm a bit newbie on PHP Proxy so, if you can write me some lines of codes with details ^^

Thanks,

Comment: This question will probably get closed as being too broad.  Might I suggest taking Grace Hopper's advice and just try it and see where you get stuck?

Comment: Actually, i'm using a 3rd party proxy but i want my server to do what this proxy does, downloading the file with the server and not directly from the host of the original file

Comment: for a very crude solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054618/how-do-i-use-my-server-as-a-proxy-to-download-files-via-php

Comment: It's what i was testing actually, with the 2nd code in the thread, i'm only downloading at 200 ko/s :(
As direct link i download up to 50 mo/s from the server and the original link..

Comment: Any way to resolve this speed issue?